# Достать ссылку на видео из файла m3u8 с помощью чистого JS

Tags: javascript, m3u

У меня есть файл формата m3u8. Как мне достать ссылку на полное видео не используя плагины и прочее?

Вот одна из строк

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=836280,CODECS="mp4a.40.2,avc1.64001f",RESOLUTION=848x480,NAME="480",PROGRESSIVE-URI="https://proxy-012.dc3.test.com/sec(tB2p6SYsvQDry0kHY3H9nWVmjANtySRgiJsPeg7wrFhqrryBSWZFQdb4zbmQQrWXJ99tex-1HnByCnNAzLh2fg)/video/480/959/483959084_mp4_h264_aac_hq.mp4#cell=core&qos_vpart=1&qos_stail=1"
https://proxy-012.dc3.test.com/sec(saQeXx3qXZg3T3rkC8HACALTVY4A6tH2mobtlBB3Wk4B4gKlIdX9BbEnrZFM8i_HinE5kVKr_sZm-2_oe9xLPyh0x6lXOOrguzm7atF7wu4)/video/480/959/483959084_mp4_h264_aac_hq.m3u8#cell=core&qos_vpart=1&qos_stail=1
```

Comment: Можно использовать регулярное выражение: `/PROGRESSIVE-URI="(.*)"/.exec(varName)[1]`, вместо `varName` нужно использовать переменную с содержимым файла.

Comment: @OliverPatterson спасибо огромное. работает))